# Is there a max number of Metal threadgroups allowed on a machine?

Tags: metal

I can only find the `maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup` property, which is determined by the hardware.

But what about the max total thread groups? Isn't this restricted by the number of SMs on a machine? Can I have as many as I want? Why?

Comment: Unless you exceed the command buffer execution time limit, threadgroups will be scheduled until all dispatched work is complete. There’s no guarantee that the entire grid executes simultaneously.

Comment: @warrenm If the number of thread groups is below the number of SMs, can I ensure that they can execute simultaneously?